# Importing MIMEMultipart

Tags: python, python-3.x

Everything that I am reading says that `email.MIMEMultipart` is included in Python's basic library, but when trying to run code that requires it I am getting the message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'email.MIMEMultipart'
```

Is there something simple that I am missing here, or do I not have this module for some reason?

```
import sys
import time
import smtplib
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`MIMEMultipart`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.mime.html#email.mime.multipart.MIMEMultipart) is not a module; it is a class in the `email.mime.multipart` module.  To import it, you have to do:

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
```

Comment: That still throws the same error for me.   
  File "C:\Users\test\python3.6\HC\test\test.py", line 8, in <module>
    from email.MIME.Multipart import MIMEMultipart
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'email.MIME'

Comment: @Brandon: Python module names are case sensitive.  It's `email.mime.multipart`, not `email.MIME.Multipart`.